# Audit log web service for Office 365

Tags: office-365, rest

I am working on developing an application that will interact with the Office 365 services. I am currently able to get the files and folders of a singed-in user using the OAuth2 authentication. I am aware that we can get the audit logs and it will be exported to Microsoft Excel.

However, my question is : Is there any web service or endpoint I can use to access the logs using REST API. For example, Box provides an api/endpoint to achieve this: http://developers.box.com/docs/#events.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Currently displaying audit log reports in REST or API is not supported by Microsoft. SharePoint online in Office 365 just supports saving an audit log report as a Microsoft Excel 2012 Preview workbook.

You can refer the following post :

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/164047.aspx

Comment: This is unfortunate.  +1 on waiting for REST access to SPO Audit logs.  A WebPart with visitor details would be nice too!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft just [announced](http://blogs.office.com/2015/04/21/announcing-the-new-office-365-management-activity-api-for-security-and-compliance-monitoring/) a preview to the Office 365 Management Activity API.

According to the announcement, this does include SharePoint Online transaction logs.

Comment: but this is only for ISV's and not for developers to consume and extract the reports.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Microsoft made the appropriate updates/upgrades, and all audit logs are available on 2016/365 under Admin Center-> Security & Compliance -> Search & Investigation. Excellent Feature for Audit, eDiscovery, Policies, Security, Data Governance, in compliance with ISO 27001. You can create alerts for specific items(Documents) or lists, or library, and all the actions will be delivered in your mail box, check in/out, view, modified...